# change css class depending on location path via controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-routing

Can someone help me on how I can switch the css class of an element based on the url path in the controller?

I tried to attempt this with code below, when I change the path to 'user' the class does not change, please help, thanks.

the html:

```
<figure data-ng-class="{'account-balance': !isVisitor, 'lang-selector': isVisitor}">
```

in the controller:

```
$scope.accountView = function(viewLocation) {
if(viewLocation === $location.path('/visitor')) {
  return $scope.isVisitor;
}
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer. The only thing is I don't know what `viewLocation` is.

I would write it like this:

`<figure data-ng-class="accountView(viewLocation)">`

The function would be:

```
$scope.accountView = function(viewLocation) {
  var res;
  if(viewLocation === $location.path('/visitor')) {
    res = 'lang-selector';
  } else {
    res = 'account-balance';
  }
  return res;
};
```

This keeps all logic in the controller and gives you more control. You could also make this a `switch` statement rather than an `if/else`. Make sure `$location` is injected in the controller.